# Push a 2-dimensional array of integers onto a stack in Java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, stack

I have 2-dimensional array of integers array[i][j] (a for loop inside a for loop) and I want to push the i and j values onto a 2-dimensional stack.

I have defined the stack as follows:

`Stack<Integer[][]> stack = new Stack<Integer[][]>()`;

How can I push i and j onto the stack?

I've tried:

```
stack.push([i][j]);
```

but Eclipse spits out:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved
>   compilation problem:      Syntax error on token "(", Expression expected
>   after this token

Answer (score 3):

The compiler is throwing up because your code is not valid syntax. You are dereferencing non-existent arrays and attempting to pass their values to your stack function, incorrectly. Try something more along the line of this:

```
stack.push(new Integer[][] {{i}, {j}});
```

Answer (score 0):

since you have added the genrics with Integer[][] , so if you declare an 2D array like

```
Integer[][] array = new Integer[10][5];
```

stack.push(array) will work not individual element